# Azure Container Service DCOS fails to deploy due to QuotaExceeded

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-container-service

I am trying to deploy Azure Container Service with DCOS orchestrator, 1 master, 1 agent, with Standard D2_v2 agent size (2 cores), West Europe, using Azure portal. I am passing validation at the end of the process, but when I click 'OK' for deployment I get error:

"QuotaExceeded\",\r\n \"message\": \"Operation results in exceeding quota limits of Core. Maximum allowed: 4, Current in use: 0, Additional requested: 6."

Why does service requires 6 cores when I am trying to use D2_v2 agent size that requires only 2 cores?

Here are the pictures with configuration and error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQgl4.jpg

I tried doing the same with azure CLI as in [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/dcos-swarm/container-service-dcos-quickstart) and got the same error.

Edit: I am using free trial service version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we try to use Azure marketplace to deploy ACS DC/OS, Azure will create one master and two nodes, at least we need 6 cores.

But **free trial** subscription with a **limit of 4 cores**.

As a workaround, we can deploy DC/OS without use Azure marketplace, we can create two VMs and deploy DC/OS on those VMs, one master and one node.

More information about deploy DC/OS on VMs, please refer to this [article](https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/administration/installing/custom/gui/).

Answer (score 0):

Because you are deploying a cluster, meaning several nodes linked together. In this case 3 nodes. You need to use other region or request additional cores for this region (use support ticket).

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using free trial version so quota increase is impossible. I've tried using several other regions and changing agent sizes but it doesn't help. The error is always the same..

Comment: I'm not sure which is the free trial version, i believe the latest azure trial offers a lot of functions, you should try and register for that

Comment: I registered at the beginning of this week so my free subsctiption is up to date. For now I've chosen "Swarm" orchestrator instead of "DC/OS" and deployment went fine.